# Is it possible to get the version of an assembly that is in internet, like onedrive?

Tags: c#

To get the version of an assembly locally I use this code:

```
Version myVersion = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(myPathToDll).Version;
```

This has the advantage that doesn't load the assembly in memory, so it is not blocked and also I don't need to transfer the whole dll if it is a remote server inside the LAN.

However, I am wondering if there are some way to check the version of the dll if this dll is the cloud, for example in onedrive or a webpage... etc.

I would like to avoid to have to download the file to the local computer and check it, because my idea it is develop an update application that checks updates at startup and to download all the dlls would make the application very slow in the startup.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not have an API endpoint on the same place where you dll exists that your application can query for the version? API could read the version from the dll, be fast and just return it to the app.

Comment: Would it not be a lot simpler to simply maintain the current version numbers within a flat file and compare with that? *would make the application very slow in the startup* do it async/in another thread then inform the user upon completion if their attention is required.

Comment: @AlexK. Right, I am thinking to have a .txt file in the same place than the dll with the version of the dll, so get the version only takes few bytes and it is very fast. If the vesion is newer, then I download the dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that using the .NET Framework by default. `AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName` doesn't support HTTP.

What you could do is this:

- Make a `HttpWebRequest` to the assembly;
- Read the first X bytes to read the metadata from the assembly;
- Dissemble the metadata and read the version.

This is a lot of work, and I can't help you with the code for it. You need to think whether it is worth the time.

Another option could be a web service that does all that for you. That might be the more straightforward option.